# Parse.com application has exceeded the request limit exception. Can I check what activity or user is causing it using Parse explorer

Tags: parse-platform

I am using Pars.com for my application and every once in a while I get the exception that the application has exceeded the request limit. Sometimes this shows in the Performance graph and some times it does not.We normally never exceed the request limit and once in a while it randomly shows 100x more activity than normal.

Is there a way to determine what API was called and or the user who is causing this increase in activity using the new Parse Analytics Explorer

Comment: You cannot be so sure that you are not exceeding the request, what if your code is in a loop, or a call back function is calling it multiple times.. It will be nice to paste the code to see how you are implementing the API Call.

Comment: Hi Clain, So part of the issue is to figure out which part of the code could be causing it. What is the best way to narrow it down. RIght now parse just tells me you made xxxx requests in the past minute and please wait. The performance graph is not showing that the requests exceeded the limit.

Comment: first case is to confirm that there are no additional API Requests made, to do this monitor your HTTP / SOAP requests. Also use break points every time you make a request , or set a counter every time an API is called and print the counter to identify the number of requests made